# Bounding trapezoid / line on interval

Tags: line, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am looking for a way to find the line (red) that optimally (least area) bounds a set of 2d points (black stars).
[image: illustration of line]

I am having trouble googling, but the following terms seem related:

- minimum bounding line on interval
- minimum bounding cone / pyramid / trapezoid
- this is a simplified case of finding a convex hull or polygon -- three sides are already known.
- chi2 minimization / linear regression
- Pareto front

If I assume the blue line is defined between (xmin, 0) and (xmax, 0), then I can parameterize the line with two points, at (xmin, ymin) and (xmax, ymax), where ymin and ymax are unknown parameters.

I need to adhere to

```
yi <= (xi - xmin) * (ymax - ymin) / (xmax - xmin) + ymin
```

for every point (xi, yi). This trivially implies ymin must be larger than the yi of the xmin point, and ymax must be larger than the yi of the xmax point.

I want to minimize the area:

```
min: A = |ymax - ymin| / 2 * (xmax - xmin)
```

which simplifies to

```
min: (ymax - ymin)^2
```

Do I need to solve this with (non-?)linear programming, exhaustive search (test the n*(n-1)/2 line combinations) or is there a easy and fast algorithmic solution?

I also know that the line will have a positive slope for my problem. I guess I can use that to eliminate points with a Pareto domination criterion: Any point (xi,yi) can remove a point (xj,yj) if xj > xi but yj < yi. That is, points that are right and below of another point can be removed. After that, testing n*(n-1)/2 line combinations may not be so bad.